# Vcorpus Rstudio combining .txt files

Tags: r

I have a directory of .txt files and need to combine then into one file.  each file would be a separate line.  I tried:

```
new_corpus <-VCorpus(DirSource("Downloads/data/"))
```

The data is in the file but I get an error

```
Error in DirSource(directory = "Downloads/data/") : 
empty directory
```

This is a bit basic but I was only given this information on how to create the corpus.  What I need to do is take this file and create one factor that is the .txt and another with an ID, in the form of:

```
ID .txt
ID .txt
.......
```

EDIT To clarify on emilliman5 comment:
I need both a data frame and a corpus.  The example I am working from used a csv file with the data already tagged for a Naive Bayes problem.  I can work through that example and all the steps.  The data I have is in a different format.  It is 2 directories (/ham and /spam) of short .txt files.  I was able to create a corpus, when I changed my command to:

> new_corpus <-VCorpus(DirSource("~/Downloads/data/"))

I have cleaned the raw data and can make DTM but at the end I will need to create a crossTable with the labels spam and ham.  I do  not understand how I insert that information into the corpus.

Comment: What does `dir("Downloads/data/")` produce?

Comment: dir("Downloads/data/") produces character(0)

Comment: That denotes the directory is empty.

Comment: if I add the "~" it reads the files --------"~/Downloads/data/"  I tried "Home/..... but that did not work.   now I need to make it a dataframe

Comment: Do you need to create a Corpus or a dataframe with an ID and .txt? You do not need one for the other. Please head over to this post to strengthen and clarify your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example